# Did Hephaestus and Aphrodite get divorced?

Tags: greek, roman, aphrodite, hephaestus

I come across every now and then that the smith god and the love goddess got a divorce. But to contrast that, I read they are still together in Roman myths and times. Though I also have contrast to that and I suppose it could be a copy of the Greek myths. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably yes.

Several writers, including Homer and Hesiod, mention that Hephaistos married [Aglaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaea), one of the three Charites. It is not entirely clear whether this happened before or after his marriage to Aphrodite, I could not find a source that explicitly mentions the order of Hephaistos's marriages. There's also a possibility that a second marriage doesn't imply a divorce. Polygamy was rare in ancient Greece, but we can't rule it out completely.

There's also the story of the birth of [Erichthonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erichthonius_of_Athens). In most versions, it is explicitly mentioned that Hephaistos's' attempt to rape Athena happens after he had been "deserted by Aphrodite". Although again this doesn't necessarily mean divorce, it certainly sounds like it.

---

You may find more details, including sources, on theoi.com:

- [Hephaestus Myths 2 Loves: Aphrodite](https://www.theoi.com/Olympios/HephaistosLoves.html#Aphrodite)
- [Hephaestus Myths 2 Loves: Athena & Gaea](https://www.theoi.com/Olympios/HephaistosLoves.html#Athena)
- [Hephaestus Myths 2 Loves: Aglaea](https://www.theoi.com/Olympios/HephaistosLoves.html#Aglaia)